# Reverse availability in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

By default, all times are assumed "available" in a Google calendar. Only once an event is inserted, the corresponding time slot is considered "busy". It is possible to define working hours, but this is not flexible. Assume you have a freelancer who is available Monday 10:00-14:00 and Thursday 11:00-16:00. And, in the week afterwards, he has different time slots. Is it possible to manually define the working hours?

Comment: They had, for a time, a lab whereby you could define available slots and people who were looking to invite you to a meeting could choose one of those slots. It didn't stay around, though, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you asking about the "normal" consumer Google Calendar, or is this part of Google Apps? They might have slightly differing functionality.

Comment: @AlE.I guess I mean "normal". I don't refer the a mobile or desktop app, but the "raw" functionality.

Comment: By "normal", I mean the user as a gmail.com mail address.

Comment: Yes, but also when it is google for business. Although I guess there's no difference. But maybe I'm wrong. Let's start with normal google user.